# How to DONE jira issue

Tags: python, jira, atlassian-python-api

How to change the status of a task in jira as completed

I'm trying to do this using the atlassian-python-api, but I get an error

**requests.exceptions.HTTPError: The status change identifier must be an integer**

This is code

```py
from atlassian import Jira

jira = Jira(url='exampe.jira.com', username=username, password=password)

status = jira.get_issue_status(issue_key)
jira.issue_transition(issue_key, status=status)
```

Comment: what is the value of "status" if you print it?

Comment: Can you show the full error log, this would show which line triggers the error and helps people understand your problem better. I am guessing that `status=status` is the problem, and the API is expecting an integer as a code for the status, and you are passing something else.

Comment: i add correct status, but i got the next error:
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: You must full Story Points

Comment: @roman, when doing the same transition in the browser, does Jira allow you to do so w/o filling some extra fields?

Answer (score 0):

The status variable supposed to be the Workflow transition ID.
you can get it from the Jira Workflow.